# MaterialUI set grid item width and spacing (e.g. have 10 items on row)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I change the width of a grid item when it is not a whole [1..12] number? For example, if I want to have 10 items in a row that is `12/10=1.2`, but when I set `xs={1.2}` I get an error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `xs` of value `1.2` supplied to `ForwardRef(Grid)`, 
expected one of [false,"auto",true,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12].
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do, I use `xs={1}` for all the item grid and add justify="space-between" to container grid.

```
<Grid container justify="space-between" > 
  <Grid item xs={1} ></Grid>
  <Grid item xs={1} ></Grid>
  <Grid item xs={1} ></Grid>
  <Grid item xs={1} ></Grid>
  <Grid item xs={1} ></Grid>
  <Grid item xs={1} ></Grid>
  <Grid item xs={1} ></Grid>
  <Grid item xs={1} ></Grid>
  <Grid item xs={1} ></Grid>
  <Grid item xs={1} ></Grid>
</Grid>
```

That way, it distributes the all item grids equally space between

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution that I am aware of atm:

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  const list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Grid container>
        {Array.from(Array(5)).map(k => {
          return <React.Fragment key={`grid-row-${k}`}>
          <Grid item xs={1} />
        {list.map((i) => (
          <Grid
            item
            xs={1}
            key={`item-${i}`}
            style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
          >
            {i}
          </Grid>
        ))}
        <Grid item xs={1} />
        </React.Fragment>
        })}
        
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```